# How do I load a JavaScript onclick in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question is pertaining to my music discovery tool that I have created. [DREAMFM](http://dreamfm.biz/)

Within a div element, I have a JavaScript that randomly selects some HTML from an array. The randomly selected HTML is then written to my document, the index. Each number in the array is a different song that is written to the HTML. The only way to get to the next new song, is to refresh the page currently. I would like to load the JavaScript onclick of a button instead of having to reload the page to get to the next song.

Currently I am using this method to reload the external JavaScript:

```
<button id="nextbtn" type="button" onclick="shuffle()" autofocus>></button>

<script>
function shuffle() {
location.reload(true); 
}
</script>
```

I would like to load only the JavaScript without reloading the entire page.

Comment: Share some of the code you have tried..

Comment: My bad, accidently added my comment as an answer...anyway, So you have a javascript file that you want to be loaded in when a user clicks on a button?

Comment: I have an external script that I would like reloaded when a button is clicked.

Comment: @telepathicvapor _"I have an external script that I would like reloaded when a button is clicked."_ Are you sure this is the functionality you need? The way I see it, all you want to do is loading some random HTML into a `div`. This can be accomplished with a single function call, without requiring you to reload your entire JavaScript code.

Comment: @JánosWeisz I am fairly certain I need to load my entire script again. How would I reload my script using a function call?

Comment: The code in your javascript file should be contained in a function. At the end of the script execute that function, to ensure your code is still executed when script is loaded. Then call that function in your `shuffle()` function, or directly from onlick of the button.

Comment: I've looked at your webpage and I guess the code that updates document with the song is this one: `document.write(random_song[random_number]);`
Note that even if you execute it another time the effect is most likely not what you expect - html content with another song would be appended to existing page instead of replacing it. You''ll need to also remove old content.

Comment: @TMG Yes I just had this happen to me when testing out some of the suggested answers. Is there a simple way to remove the old content before adding the new content? Or am I just better off leaving the site working as it is?

Comment: Create an empty div with some id (lets assume id=songcontent) in your html and then use for example `$('#songcontent').html(random_song[random_number]);` instead of `document.write()`.

Comment: @TMG This seems to be on the right track for sure, but I am having some issues. I have my JS contained within the function with the updated aspect you suggested. The script does not execute if the div element is empty, and only if the JS src is within it. This causes the script to be run twice and doesn't work correctly. Suggestions?

Thank you for your time I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not write your code / Do not implement your JS file inline with html. Wrap your code inside a function and call it as you need. Onload or Onclick:

```
function displayRandomSong(){
// put all of Your current code here if there is no function and
// every thing is pure javascript codes. I think this meets your need.

// However if your JS file is a complex of many functions, There is always 
// a function Which is triggered before others. Call that function here
// For example:
// startRandomization()
 }
```

So the html would be this:

```
<a onclick="displayRandomSong()">inline refresh</a>
```

Comment: I think he is trying to load the external script on click.

Comment: There is no need to load an external script in javascript. implementing that file and Calling a function is enough.

Comment: @TedJohnson With the title _"How do I load a JavaScript onclick in HTML?"_ it is indeed confusing, but I think OP wants to load random _HTML_ into a `div` _using_ JavaScript.

Comment: Yes I am trying to reload an external javascript when a button is clicked.

Comment: I have edited the answer about wrapping code inside a function. Please check again.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour So am I to paste my entire JS within the function? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Currently I am using this method to reload the JavaScript:

<button id="nextbtn" type="button" onclick="shuffle()" autofocus>></button>

<script>
 function shuffle() {
 location.reload(true);
 }
</script>

I would like to load only the JavaScript without reloading the entire page.

Comment: If you JS is only one function, just call that function otherwise Please check my comments in Edited answer again.